# Javascript Preload Image after window has loaded

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I am working on a project that requires a user to load an image into canvas which is placed in a lightbox based on the selection they make.

None of the image are loaded before the user clicks a button, then in an XHR request the image URLs are received..

I am having an issue with loading images and postponing the execution of the code that follows...

My image loading function looks like this..

```
function preloadImage(url){
    var img = new Image();
        if (!img.complete) {
            console.log('not complete');
            //return false;
        }
        if (typeof img.naturalWidth != "undefined" && img.naturalWidth == 0) {
            console.log('no width');
            //return false;
        }
    img.onerror='Image failed to load...';
    img.src = url;
}
```

and in code I call it before I set my canvas element... this...

```
preloadImage(url);
setstage(url);
```

The canvas sometimes gets the image in time to set my stage but sometimes not so I have a blank stage :/. Is there a way I can do this and resolve this image pre-loading issue somehow?

Comment: Just use the `onload` event of your image.

Comment: could you call setstage within preloadimage?

Comment: mmm.. I think I could rewrite the code to do that,, yes... You mean to place img.onload = function() { // execute setstage(url) here }; in the preload function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was really pressured to come up with a fairly solid and stable solution and I ended up doing quite a bit of reading,,, from a collection of online articles and other developers' experiences I derived a solid preloaded with a callback...

The function is simply this...

```
function preloadimages(arr){
    var newimages=[], loadedimages=0
    var postaction=function(){}
    var arr=(typeof arr!="object")? [arr] : arr
    function imageloadpost(){
        loadedimages++
        if (loadedimages==arr.length){
            postaction(newimages) //call postaction and pass in newimages array as parameter
        }
    }
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        newimages[i]=new Image()
        newimages[i].src=arr[i]
        newimages[i].onload=function(){
            imageloadpost()
        }
        newimages[i].onerror=function(){
            imageloadpost()
        }
    }
    return { //return blank object with done() method
        done:function(f){
            postaction=f || postaction //remember user defined callback functions to be called when images load
        }
    }
}
```

And a simple use case is

```
 preloadimages(IMAGES-ARRAY).done(function(images){
      // code that executes after all images are preloaded
  });
```

If anyone has improvements you are welcome to expand and comment,, maybe someone will benefit from this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using callback in preloadImage:

```
 function preloadImage(url, callback) {

    var img = new Image();

    img.onerror = function() {

        callback('error', url, img);
    };

    img.onload = function() {

        callback(null, url, img);
    };

    img.src = url;
}

preloadImage(url, function(err, url, img) {

    if (err) {
        console.log('something wrong!!', url);
        return;
    }

    //get more params from img..
    setstage(url);
});
```

..

```
function foo() {

    //here are some params
    var srcx = 1, id = 2, x = 3, y = 4;

    preloadImage(url, function(err, url, img) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('something wrong!!', url);
            return;
        }

        //more params
        var width = 5, height = 6;

        setstage(srcx, id, x, y, width, height);
    });
}
```

Comment: I presume my callback function can have x parameters (not just one)? The actual function I use receives 6 params. setstage( srcx, id, x, y, width, height )

Comment: I'm not sure what these params mean, but you can get them from the img element itself, right?

Comment: no,, no,, the params are passed to set stage function that creates stage on canvas element, they are not from the image they are "for the image" as it will be on the canvas..

Comment: Sorry, I may not get your point. But callback is just a function param passed in to preloadImage, nothing to do with "setstage". you can call preloadImage anywhere, like in foo, and pass any params to setstage only if these params are in scope.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. The simplest would be to wait to call `setStage` until the `img.onload` event fires. If you need to do it in the same scope as the `preloadImage(url)` for whatever reason (not sure what reason that might be), you could do the next step via a promise returned in the `image.onload`callback.